# PHP MYSQL : why i am getting this warning?

Tags: php, mysql

When I use

```
mysql_affected_rows($result);
```

...in php then I get below warning how to remove it?

> Warning: mysql_affected_rows(): supplied resource is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in  C:\wamp\www\st_db_1\search_db.php on line 60

Comment: I'm afraid you will need to show us more code than that to get a reasonable answer. The reason it's happening is because $result is not a valid MySQL link resource (so if it's being set to the return value of mysql_query(), then perhaps the query you are running is incorrect causing mysql_query to return false instead).

Comment: I'm assuming, from what I've experienced recently, that either what's inside $result is not what is expected, or that there's actually nothing inside $result. Could you please provide more info?

Comment: $query = "INSERT INTO 
               `$clas` (`adm_no`, `adm_dt`, `name`, `dob`, `f_name`, `f_office`, `f_o_no`, `m_name`, `m_office`, `addr`, `pho_no`,`id`)
              VALUES ('$_SESSION[adm_no]', '$adm_dt', '$name',  '$dob', '$f_name', '$f_office', '$f_o_no', '$m_name', '$m_office', '$addr', '$pho_no', '1');";
$result = mysql_query($query, $connection);

Comment: Please read this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain

Comment: You have an error in your query, if you want some real help, provide the query in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume $result = mysql_query() ??

Don't pass it that variable, you can pass it the connection link $variable or just use mysql_affected_rows();

Answer (score 1):

$result must be the link identifier not the query example

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');

// will return for the most recent connection
echo mysql_affected_rows();

// will return for $link connection defined 2 rows up
echo mysql_affected_rows($link);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if($result)
{
    mysql_affected_rows($result);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query did not produce a valid result.
Try `echo mysql_error()` before calling `mysql_affected_rows()`.